# Palm Pilot Graffiti

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction, optical-char-recognition

I have been completely unable to find details on the underlying model that is used for the Palm Pilot Graffiti handwriting recognition. Given the computing power available for handheld PDA technology, I have always been quite surprised this was possible at that time. I was hoping for a source with information about the model, e.g., features, recognition method, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful it is, but the Palm system was "stolen" from Xerox's **Unistrokes** system, [which was written up here.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=169093)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a good explanation of some of the methods used in projects like GRAIL look here:

## [Back to the Future of Hand Writing Recognition](https://jackschaedler.github.io/handwriting-recognition/)

Comment: That may have been the best tutorial I have ever gone through. After a single pass I feel vaguely confident that I could implement a simple detector on a microcontroller. It is an unbelievably simple approach to a seemingly very complicated problem. Thanks.

Comment: This one is a great catch! +1.

Answer (score 3):

Surprised?  DARPA ([GRAIL project](http://www.osnews.com/story/26838/Palm_I_m_ready_to_wallow_now/page2/)?, et.al.) supported handwriting recognition research circa 3 decades earlier, and on mainframes less powerful than a PalmPilot 1000.

Hawkins talks a bit about implementing Graffiti in a [Computer History Museum oral history](http://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102658113).

Comment: Your link for the oral history is bad.

Comment: seems to be, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

It seems most of the data is in [Graffiti (Palm OS) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graffiti_(Palm_OS)).
It seems the technology is related to [Unistrokes technology (U.S. Patent 5,596,656, granted in 1997)](https://www.google.com/patents/US5596656).

Since the model relies on single stroke and using *symbols that are exceptionally well separated from each other graphically* I would be assume parameterizing the stroke would be a great way to get well separated features. Just the coordinate and the relation between them will be perfect.

Comment: I had looked this up on Wikipedia before I asked the question, but it wasn't clear to me whether the patent dispute was over a unistroke input method or the actual recognition system design. I figured that it was the former as the patent was repeatedly disputed.

Comment: Do you know if the recognition system was the same?

Comment: Well, if they made the effort to only support "Single Stroke" which leaves very little to discern between the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

if you can get into the IEEE Explore Library

Pull up

D. J. Burr, "Designing a Handwriting Reader," in IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, vol. PAMI-5, no. 5, pp. 554-559, Sept. 1983.

and then look at the citations, which include both the Palm and Xerox Patents.  Xerox claimed that Palm infringed so you might pick up some clues.